# MongoDB Reverse Wildcard Search on Arrays

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, match, where-clause

I'm trying to get a something from a DB of the form:

```
{
  names: [{
    name: "this has a {variable}"
  }]
}
```

By being able to pass it something like **"this has a pizza"**. i.e. {variable} is a wildcard inside of the value.

At the moment I've been writing something of the form:

```
var search = "this has a pizza";
var query = {
  names: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $where: '"' + search + '".match("\"+this.myRegex+"\")'
    }
  }
}
```

For which I have create a new entry on creation:

```
name.myRegex = name.myRegex.replace(/{.*?}/g, "(.*?)");
```

Alas, as well as the above not working I also think this is a terrible way to accomplish this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using `$regex` query operator - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ ?

Comment: @Bardzuśny I believe the "regex" in this case is stored in the document and this is trying to match a "string" to the regex in the document. You cannot use `$where` inside `$elemMatch`. To use `$where` you need all the logic to traverse the array in the JavaScript code and cannot borrow from the other operators. The `this` in `$where` is the whole document and is not applied to a field or any other level.